# Installed a new LCD screen on iPod but concerned to charge

Tags: ipod-touch, battery, screen, repair

As stated, I just installed a new ipod touch 4th generation LCD. As many youtube tutorial layout I went ahead after installing my LCD to power on the screen. However, here is my dilemma, the battery has no charge. So I am debating on charging the itouch through my laptop. But I am worried I may damage it. This is because I before when I tried installing another LCD, I went to charge it and then got the white screen of death. However, maybe it was a defective screen and it was just a false positive.

Is it ok to charge the screen after I install the L cable and center cable of the Itouch? please give answers if you are 100% certain of this because I am low on money and I can't afford to purchase another screen.

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Nobody can answer that with 100% certainty.

We do not know your workmanship skills, and if you made any errors.

You could charge the battery without the screen connected. Using the Computer to charge it is safer anyway since the current from computer is limited and less then from the charger for what ever is it worth.